# Calculate MIPS after running gprof?

Tags: c, debugging, profiling, signal-processing

My audio DSP algorithm processes input sound file (45 seconds of 16 kHz audio). After simulation is done, `gprof` profiler tells me:

`Cycles: total = 6846310893`

Is this enough information to calculate this algorithm's "MIPS"?

Let's say my target DSP processor is "100 MIPS".
How much will this algo take out of those 100?

**Edit**:
Processor executes 1 instruction per cycle.
Processor runs at 600 MHz.

Comment: If by "MIPS" you mean "millions of instructions per second", then your question doesn't even make sense.  That's a measure of a processor's capabilities, not a characteristic of a program or algorithm.

Comment: Moreover, I don't know about your particular DSP, but it is common for processors to take more than one cycle to execute an instruction, so the number of cycles expended during a computation does not directly tell you how many instructions were executed.  In any case, you need the corresponding clock rate to convert a cycle count to a time.

Comment: Added more info. I agree, but I think it is clear what the question is about.

Comment: Finally, the cost, in instruction equivalents, of a particular computation is not "taken out of" a processor's processing rate in any absolute sense.  Rather, the two together give you a lower bound on how long the computation will take.

Comment: It took 6846310893 cycles to process 45 sec * 16000 audio samples, which gives 9508.76 cycles/ audio sample. If DSP clock runs at 600 MHz (and 1 instruction per cycle), this gives 63100 samples/sec. Meaning my DSP can run about 4 mono channels through this algorithm, no more (4 * 16000 Hz). So if DSP runs 600 MIPS, this algo takes about 1/4, 150 MIPS. Not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: If you're asking about how many audio streams your target DSP can process *in real time*, then you should certainly clarify your question to so indicate.

Comment: But it also sounds like you have answered that question yourself, already.

Comment: No, that's not what I was asking. I wanted to know algorithms part in the overall processor "MIPS" capability.

Comment: Again, @Danijel, an algorithm has no part in or direct relation to the processing capacity of the machine on which it runs.  "MIPS" is not meaningfully defined for algorithms.  Rather, a particular job that uses an algorithm on specific input data involves executing a some number of instructions (measurable in MI, not MIPS), and the speed of the processor on which it runs (*that* measurable in MIPS) puts a lower bound on the time it will take to run that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...
`6846310893` cycles per `45` seconds is: `152.14` "MIPS", meaning my 600 MHz processor can (nearly) execute 4 of these in real-time.